# ¿Cómo crear un árbol binario en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array-bidimensional, árboles-binarios, binario, árboles

Estoy tratando de recrear y recorrer esta estructura de árbol binario, pero las coordenadas de cada nodo están representadas de la siguiente manera. Donde el primer dígito es el eje Y, y el segundo dígito es el eje X.

```
// LVL 1 --------->                     (1,1)
// LVL 2 --------->          (2,1)                (2,2)
// LVL 3 --------->     (3,1)    (3,2)       (3,3)     (3,4)
// LVL 4 --------->  (4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)  (4,5)(4,6)(4,7)(4,8)
```

Problemas:
-No se como crear esta estructura y guardarla en un array (puede ser por medio de un ciclo for, while etc..).
-En caso tal de haber creado el árbol en orden por niveles (llenándolo de arriba a abajo y de derecha a izquierda), y si por alguna razón elimino un elemento como el "(2,1)" de la lista me quedaría el siguiente array: [(1,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2), etc...]

```
// LVL 1 --------->                    (1,1)
// LVL 2 --------->         |FALTA|               (2,2)
// LVL 3 --------->     (3,1)    (3,2)       (3,3)     (3,4)
// LVL 4 --------->  (4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)  (4,5)(4,6)(4,7)(4,8)
```

Entonces estaría faltando el elemento (2,1), el caso es que tendría que recorrer el array y si falta un "padre", identificarlo e insertarlo nuevamente en la posición que falta.

¡¡¡Muchas gracias de antemano colegas!!!

Comment: Y a partir de qué datos quieres crear el árbol?

Comment: Hola Fedex7501, la idea es asociar un ID= x a la próxima posición vacía o disponible en el árbol recorriéndolo de arriba-abajo y de derecha a izquierda, por decirlo de alguna manera "en orden".

Comment: Ahora que lo dices era bastante obvio. Lo único que no me queda claro es de qué forma quieres guardarlo en el array. El ejemplo que diste no lo deja claro.

Comment: nada, ya entendí. hoy estoy un poco lento

Comment: Tal vez se puede guardar como un objeto en el array, generando un id con Math.random(), y asignándolo a la próxima posición disponible en el árbol.
{
  id: numRandom,
  pos: (y,x)
}
O algo parecido...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si entendí bien:

```js
let arr = [] //Creamos el arreglo
let y
let x

//Iteramos de arriba hacia abajo y de izquierda a derecha
for (y = 1; y <= 4; y++){
  for (x = 1; x <= Math.pow(2, y-1); x++){
    arr.push({y, x})
  }
}

//Eliminamos dos elementos
arr.splice(1, 1)
arr.splice(3, 1)

//Buscamos elementos faltantes
y = 1
x = 1

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if (arr[i].x !== x || arr[i].y !== y){ //Si el elemento no corresponde a la posición actual...
    arr.splice(i, 0, {y, x}) //Agregamos el elemento faltante
  }

  //Avanzamos las coordenadas
  x++
  if (x > Math.pow(2, y-1)){
    x = 1
    y++
  }
}

console.log(arr) //Imprime el arreglo completo
```

Comment:  Eso es!!! Muchas gracias CRACK!!!